# Why won't my self.init autofill in a convenience initializer?

Tags: swift, xcode

I don't know if this is important or not, but this takes place in an `extension`.

Anyways, my teacher today had us create a convenience initializer in an extension to our model. When he demonstrated, Xcode's autofill filled in the initializer for him, but gave me nothing. I asked about that, but we couldn't figure it out. Some of us in the class had it work while others didn't.

Essentially, we had this:

```swift
extension Entry {

    //existing initializer
    convenience init(title: String, body: String) {
        self.init()
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
    }

    // new initializer we were creating
    convenience init(representation: EntryRepresentation) {
        // this next line would **NOT** autofill no matter what I tried
        // (both waiting, backing up and retyping a little, or hitting esc)
        // it wouldn't even show other, non convenience inits
        self.init(title: representation.title, body: representation.body)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Later, after a bit of troubleshooting (trust me, cleaning the build folder is ineffective here), I realized that our teacher was working off a template he had from Swift 4.2 days and hadn't updated the template to Swift 5, while I had started a new project and was using Swift 5 as my compiler version. Upon toggling this in Xcode, 4.2 made the autofill work, while 5 broke it.

Obviously, toggling this buried setting is a poopy workaround for this issue, so here's a decent workaround:

1. In my case, I would write out:

   - `Entry.init(`
2. ...which will give me my autofill options
3. use autofill to get

   - `Entry.init(title: <#String#>, body: <#String#>)`
4. Just replace the class name with "self" to get

   - `self.init(title: <#String#>, body: <#String#>)`

Comment: That sounds like a regression (bug), file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com